# How to use `tail` with `timeout` in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to output the last few lines of a script but also cut it off after 5 seconds.  I can output the first few easily

```
timeout 5 ./code-c|head

4 (11 - 7) 0.000003s
6 (19 - 13) 0.000018s
8 (37 - 29) 0.000020s
14 (73 - 59) 0.000022s
24 (137 - 113) 0.000024s
30 (227 - 197) 0.000031s
32 (433 - 401) 0.000038s
48 (557 - 509) 0.000044s
50 (769 - 719) 0.000051s
54 (1283 - 1229) 0.000065s
```

But if I try

```
timeout 5 ./code-c|tail
```

I just get

```
Terminated
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Probably not the "right" way but you can use a loop `while timeout 5 ./code-c;do :;done | tail`

Comment: @123 That does work! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the pipe is closed when the code-c is terminated with non-zero exit status. Add a command that's successful to prevent it

```
(timeout 5 ./code-c || true ) | tail
```

or

```
(timeout 5 ./code-c || : ) | tail
```

Comment: That is very clever! Thank you.

Comment: @eleanora : is effectively a command that just returns true and does nothing else.

Comment: I also discovered the command `timed-run`. `timed-run 5 ./code-c |tail` works just fine.

Comment: Used to look at k8s app log. ```kubectl exec webapp -- timeout -t  20 tail -f /log/app.log```